# Ajax изменение данных и их вывод в таблице

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Всех приветствую!

Хочу сделать вывод данных в таблицу из БД.
В результате получить таблицу с возможностью редактирования в каждой строчке хотя бы 1 параметра. Также нужно фильтровать таблицу по чекбоксам тоже без перезагрузки.

Некоторые действия по отдельности я могу произвести. Однако еще не обладаю достаточными знаниями чтобы все это совместить.

Данные которые мне нужно вывести хранятся в ячейках БД в виде массива:

```
{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3","d":"4"}
```

Данные получаю из БД при помощи **json_decode** в самой php странице и дальше обращаясь к каждому элементу формирую таблицу.

Дальше вопросы. Для лучшего понимания я разделю их на этапы. Если знаете варианты решения какого-то из этих пунктов - прошу подсказать.

1. Как мне отследить какую конкретно строку таблицы изменили чтобы передать измененные значения? (Думаю присваивать каждому **tr** свой **id** и потом его отслеживать как-то)
2. Как мне сформировать запрос к БД после полученных изменений, чтобы из всего массива что записан в ячейку изменились только те данные что были переданы через ajax? (Я вижу это так: в php проверяю какое поле было изменено и в **INSERT** передаю то что изменилось. Только не пойму как именно мне передать одно значение из всех.)
3. Как после изменения данных в БД вернуть их обратно на страницу? (После **INSERT** снова взять все через **SELECT** и сформировать массив, который потом через **json_encode** вернуть в js?)
4. После получения js'ом массива данных как их вставить в строку, которую изменили? Формировать таблицу заново или можно как-то прописать только ту строку что меняли?

Ну еще вопрос по чекбоксам. Как отследить их нажатие, если их несколько и как в php их обработать чтобы показать только те строки которые соответствуют нажатым чекбоксам?

PS:
Есть ли смысл все возвращать из БД или достаточно передать запись, а через js отобразить изменения? И только при обновлении страницы все заново загружать.
Как эти моменты делают в реальных проектах?

Comment: Слишкм много вопросов в одном вопросе. Лучше разбейте на маленькие, но конкретные вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

**НЕ ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ ОТВЕТОМ, УЧИТЫВАТЬ КАК РЕКОМЕНДАЦИИ:**

1. Хранить таблицу в БД указывая данные о ячейке, поля `id, row, column, data`, достать с базы всё с сортировкой по `row` и `column` перебрать через `foreach`;
2. При изменении ячейки логика такова, мы передаем её `id` и `data`, без `row` и `col` чтобы обновить данные в ячейке, и перерисовываем всю таблицу, лучше создать метод который просто будет постоянно перерисовывать не 1 элемент который изменили, а всю таблицу, что-то типа `refresh_table`, в дальнейшем это может сыграть свою роль!
3. Обновление таблицы лучше закрыть в php, т.е. ajax-ом приходит только html, который вставляется в нужную область страницы, если есть редактор инициализацию можно тамже собрать либо обновить в javascript.